# IE 10 issue with FCk editor

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer-10, fckeditor

I am using Fckeditor version 2  in my web application  . It works in IE7, IE8 and IE9 but  does not work in IE10  . The editor  displayed in IE10 but I cannot  type text in the editor  . Can any one give me a solution?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you have a link? I use CKEditor with IE10 quite often and it works fine.

Comment: I didnot get any error . Not able to type text in IE10 version only.

Comment: Hmm, what version of CKEditor are you using? If yo go to http://ckeditor.com/demo does it work for you in IE10? If it does and yours doesn't, it's an issue with the code or the version. Also, can you include some code to tell use how you include CKEditor onto your page? We need a little info to start working on the problem :)

Comment: Why don't you check CKEditor forums? They already wrote many posts about this.

Comment: @Nenotlep: asker specifically mentions *FCK*editor, not *CK*editor, and mentions version 2.

Comment: @bizzehdee Check edit history! When I asked it said "I am using ckeditor in my web application .It can be supported in IE7,IE8,IE9 but cannot supported in IE10 . The editor is displaying in IE10 but cannot able to type text in editor .Any one give me the solutions ?". I even edited this myself after that and added some tags. >_<!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

to emulate IE9. The tag must be placed just after the opening  tag.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.The above tag working fine in IE10 browser with documentation mode IE9, but does not work in IE10 browser with standard mode...